# Accuracy of floating point calculations: is something converting rational -> double-float?

Tags: common-lisp, numerical-methods, sbcl

**Background**

I'm working with numerical routines that require at least 15 decimal places of accuracy in the double-float domain.  For the most part, this has never been a problem.  However when implementing lanczos sums I am only getting 5/6 digits of accuracy when compared to Boost/Cephes (both of these use the same algorithm and coefficients)

My first thought was "Boost and Cephes use long-doubles, and I'm using double-floats", so I converted the coefficients to rationals.  It's a simple algorithm with no floating point contagion that I can see, so in theory that should have solved any problem with the accuracy of the coefficients.  It doesn't; whether I use double-float coefficients or rationals, the answers are the same.

**The Code**

The C code below comes from Boost's [evaluate_rational](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/math/tools/rational.hpp) function and the coefficients selected are n=13 and G=6.024680040776729583740234375L0.  This is supposed to give the best accuracy for 64 bit floats (I could have selected other coefficients, but they're all long-double).

Here's the C code

```
template <class T>
   static T lanczos_sum_expG_scaled(const T& z)
   {
      static const T num[13] = {
         static_cast<T>(56906521.91347156388090791033559122686859L),
         static_cast<T>(103794043.1163445451906271053616070238554L),
         static_cast<T>(86363131.28813859145546927288977868422342L),
         static_cast<T>(43338889.32467613834773723740590533316085L),
         static_cast<T>(14605578.08768506808414169982791359218571L),
         static_cast<T>(3481712.15498064590882071018964774556468L),
         static_cast<T>(601859.6171681098786670226533699352302507L),
         static_cast<T>(75999.29304014542649875303443598909137092L),
         static_cast<T>(6955.999602515376140356310115515198987526L),
         static_cast<T>(449.9445569063168119446858607650988409623L),
         static_cast<T>(19.51992788247617482847860966235652136208L),
         static_cast<T>(0.5098416655656676188125178644804694509993L),
         static_cast<T>(0.006061842346248906525783753964555936883222L)
      };
      static const BOOST_MATH_INT_TABLE_TYPE(T, std::uint32_t) denom[13] = {
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(0u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(39916800u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(120543840u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(150917976u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(105258076u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(45995730u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(13339535u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(2637558u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(357423u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(32670u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(1925u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(66u),
         static_cast<std::uint32_t>(1u)
      };
      return boost::math::tools::evaluate_rational(num, denom, z);

template <class T, class U, class V>
V evaluate_rational(const T* num, const U* denom, const V& z_, std::size_t count) BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(V)
{
   V z(z_);
   V s1, s2;
   if(z <= 1)
   {
      s1 = static_cast<V>(num[count-1]);
      s2 = static_cast<V>(denom[count-1]);
      for(int i = (int)count - 2; i >= 0; --i)
      {
         s1 *= z;
         s2 *= z;
         s1 += num[i];
         s2 += denom[i];
      }
   }
   else
   {
      z = 1 / z;
      s1 = static_cast<V>(num[0]);
      s2 = static_cast<V>(denom[0]);
      for(unsigned i = 1; i < count; ++i)
      {
         s1 *= z;
         s2 *= z;
         s1 += num[i];
         s2 += denom[i];
      }
   }
   return s1 / s2;
}
```

and the corresponding Common Lisp translation.  The rational coefficients were obtained by using CLISP and `rationalize`.

```lisp
(defparameter lanczos-13-numerator-scaled
  (make-array 13
          :initial-contents '(5690652191347156388090791033559122686859/100000000000000000000000000000000
                  518970215581722725953135526808035119277/5000000000000000000000000000000
                  4318156564406929572773463644488934211171/50000000000000000000000000000000
                  866777786493522766954744748118106663217/20000000000000000000000000000000
                  1460557808768506808414169982791359218571/100000000000000000000000000000000
                  87042803874516147720517754741193639117/25000000000000000000000000000000
                  6018596171681098786670226533699352302507/10000000000000000000000000000000000
                  1899982326003635662468825860899727284273/25000000000000000000000000000000000
                  3477999801257688070178155057757599493763/500000000000000000000000000000000000
                  4499445569063168119446858607650988409623/10000000000000000000000000000000000000
                  121999549265476092677991310389728258513/6250000000000000000000000000000000000
                  5098416655656676188125178644804694509993/10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                  3030921173124453262891876982277968441611/500000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
          :element-type 'rational))

(defparameter lanczos-13-denominator
  (make-array 13
          :initial-contents '(0
                  39916800
                  120543840
                  150917976
                  105258076
                  45995730
                  13339535
                  2637558
                  357423
                  32677
                  1925
                  66
                  1)
          :element-type 'rational))

(defun evaluate-rational (numerator denominator z)
  ;; (declare (double-float z))
  (assert (= (length numerator)
         (length denominator)) () "Numerator and denominator must be of the same length")
  (let (s1 s2)
    (if (<= z 1)
    (progn
      (setf s1 (aref numerator   (1- (length numerator)))
        s2 (aref denominator (1- (length denominator))))
      (loop for i from (- (length numerator) 2) downto 0
        do  (setf s1 (* s1 z)
              s1 (+ s1 (aref numerator i))
              s2 (* s2 z)
              s2 (+ s2 (aref denominator i)))))
    (progn
      (setf z (/ z)
        s1 (aref numerator 0)
        s2 (aref denominator 0))
      (loop for i from 1 below (length numerator)
        do (setf s1 (* s1 z)
             s1 (+ s1 (aref numerator i))
             s2 (* s2 z)
             s2 (+ s2 (aref denominator i)))
        )))
    (/ s1 s2)))

(defun lanczos-sum (x &key (scaled t))
  "Return the Lanczos sum for x, exp(g), possibly normalised"
 ;; (declare (double-float x))
  (if scaled
      (evaluate-rational lanczos-13-numerator-scaled lanczos-13-denominator x)
      (evaluate-rational lanczos-13-numerator lanczos-13-denominator x)))
```

The Lisp version will give 5/6 digits of accuracy in comparison to Cephes/Boost. For example:

```
LS-USER> (lanczos::lanczos-sum 79.50051116943359375d0)
0.007539495225797168d0
LS-USER> (cephes:lanczos-sum-scaled 79.50051116943359375d0)
0.007539542760993982d0
```

using a rational for `x` doesn't help:

```
CL-USER> (lanczos::lanczos-sum (rationalize 79.50051116943359375d0))
13651753323161301968358397968419859170434718739538108351630041579990307212168430280955832885058333515240792977193277162131291/1810698583169123197442845358696532421045761520142499578707004305761239420788152112760500000000000000000000000000000000000000000
CL-USER> (float * 1d0)
0.0075394952257971685d0
```

**Converting the Coefficients**

Using CLISP:

```
(SETF (EXT:LONG-FLOAT-DIGITS) 3322)
```

```lisp
(defparameter boost-numerator-scaled '(56906521.91347156388090791033559122686859L0
                       103794043.1163445451906271053616070238554L0
                       86363131.28813859145546927288977868422342L0
                       43338889.32467613834773723740590533316085L0
                       14605578.08768506808414169982791359218571L0
                       3481712.15498064590882071018964774556468L0
                       601859.6171681098786670226533699352302507L0
                       75999.29304014542649875303443598909137092L0
                       6955.999602515376140356310115515198987526L0
                       449.9445569063168119446858607650988409623L0
                       19.51992788247617482847860966235652136208L0
                       0.5098416655656676188125178644804694509993L0
                       0.006061842346248906525783753964555936883222L0))

(defparameter boost-numerator '(23531376880.41075968857200767445163675473L0
                42919803642.64909876895789904700198885093L0
                35711959237.35566804944018545154716670596L0
                17921034426.03720969991975575445893111267L0
                6039542586.35202800506429164430729792107L0
                1439720407.311721673663223072794912393972L0
                248874557.8620541565114603864132294232163L0
                31426415.58540019438061423162831820536287L0
                2876370.628935372441225409051620849613599L0
                186056.2653952234950402949897160456992822L0
                8071.672002365816210638002902272250613822L0
                210.8242777515793458725097339207133627117L0
                2.506628274631000270164908177133837338626L0))

(defparameter boost-denominator '(0
                  39916800
                  120543840
                  150917976
                  105258076
                  45995730
                  13339535
                  2637558
                  357423
                  32670
                  1925
                  66
                  1))

(defun rationalize-coefficients (coeff)
  (map 'list #'rationalize coeff))

(defun floatify-coefficients (coeff)
  (map 'list #'(lambda (x)
         (float x 1L0))
       coeff))
```

and using this on the scaled numerator:

```lisp
(rationalize-coefficients boost-numerator-scaled)
(5690652191347156388090791033559122686859/100000000000000000000000000000000
 518970215581722725953135526808035119277/5000000000000000000000000000000
 4318156564406929572773463644488934211171/50000000000000000000000000000000
 866777786493522766954744748118106663217/20000000000000000000000000000000
 1460557808768506808414169982791359218571/100000000000000000000000000000000
 87042803874516147720517754741193639117/25000000000000000000000000000000
 6018596171681098786670226533699352302507/10000000000000000000000000000000000
 1899982326003635662468825860899727284273/25000000000000000000000000000000000
 3477999801257688070178155057757599493763/500000000000000000000000000000000000
 4499445569063168119446858607650988409623/10000000000000000000000000000000000000
 121999549265476092677991310389728258513/6250000000000000000000000000000000000
 5098416655656676188125178644804694509993/10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 3030921173124453262891876982277968441611/500000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

You can see that these are the coefficients I'm using. Just to double check:

```
(floatify-coefficients *)
(5.690652191347156388090791033559122686859L7 1.037940431163445451906271053616070238554L8
 8.636313128813859145546927288977868422342L7 4.333888932467613834773723740590533316085L7
 1.460557808768506808414169982791359218571L7 3481712.15498064590882071018964774556468L0
 601859.6171681098786670226533699352302507L0 75999.29304014542649875303443598909137092L0
 6955.999602515376140356310115515198987526L0 449.9445569063168119446858607650988409623L0
 19.51992788247617482847860966235652136208L0 0.5098416655656676188125178644804694509993L0
 0.006061842346248906525783753964555936883222L0)
```

Added post-comment by a community member:

Back on SBCL:

```
LS-USER> (defparameter *sample-double* 79.5005111694336d0)
*SAMPLE-DOUBLE*
LS-USER> (defparameter *cephes-answer* 0.007539542760993982d0)
*CEPHES-ANSWER*
LS-USER> (= 79.50051116943359375d0 *sample-double*)
T
LS-USER> (- (lanczos::lanczos-sum *sample-double*) *cephes-answer*)
-4.7535196814364744d-8
LS-USER> (- (cephes:lanczos-sum-scaled 79.5005111694336d0)
            (float (lanczos::lanczos-sum (rationalize 79.5005111694336d0)) 1d0))
4.753519681349738d-8
```

So it seems SBCL is rather less accurate in this case.

Comment: `evaluate-rational` is multiplying `s1` and `s2` with `z`, so if you call it with `z` being a float, `s1` and `s2` will also turn into floats. When you tried giving it a rational argument, you used `float` to turn the rational result into a float, thus throwing away all the precision. How does it look if you use a library like [decimals](https://github.com/tlikonen/cl-decimals) to format it?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried with both rational and double-float `z` and the results are the same.

Comment: You have to use a rational, and you can't convert it into a float at the end either, because that loses precision. CL doesn't have a built-in way to print rationals as decimals without converting them into a float, so you should use a library to do that. The rational result you got, rounded to 50 decimal places, seems to be `0.00753949522579716871003179740985746093388057496346`

Comment: @jkiiski this is not some fine detail of rational->float conversion.  This is a result which is grossly wrong.

Comment: @ignisvolens The result is different than what you get with 16 byte floating point math, but have you actually confirmed that it is wrong? The floating point math isn't going to be precise either, e.g. `56906521.91347156388090791033559122686859L` is rounded to `56906521.913471563880907910336` etc.

Comment: @jkiiski: yes, we have now confirmed that is is wrong.

Comment: @ignisvolens If you're referring to the code in your answer, it doesn't confirm that. You're converting the rationals into floats, which does reproduce the loss of precision from the c++ code, but that doesn't mean that the result is better than what SBCL rational math gives. Remember that the result from the c++ code isn't precise; the inputs are already rounded and the multiplication will compound the rounding errors, so arbitrary precision math will inevitably give a different result. You should check it with some more trusted arbitrary precision math software to see if it matches SBCL.

Comment: @jkiiski: I am referring to the fact that *we found the error in the code OP was running which caused the answers to be grossly different than the C++ answer* and it has nothing to do with rational-to-float conversion.  With that error corrected the answer for all implementations we've tried is identical to or minutely different from (in the completely-rational case) to the C++ answer.  At the point where the problem has been solved it's generally no longer worth looking for other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conversion to floats happens if you are doing rational arithmetic.  If you hand the function a float argument then of course you are not doing rational arithmetic.

In the first version of this answer I assumed that your conversion of the C++ values to floats was wrong somehow and suggested you parse them differently.

However I checked that and I am getting the same values you are.

With these values (see below):

```
cl-user> *cephes-answer*
0.007539542760993982d0
cl-user> *sample-double*
79.5005111694336d0
cl-user> (= 79.50051116943359375d0 *sample-double*)
t
cl-user> (- (lanczos-sum *sample-double*) *cephes-answer*)
0.0d0
cl-user> (- (lanczos-sum (rationalize *sample-double*)) *cephes-answer*)
1.734723475976807d-18
```

This is SBCL, trunk of a few days ago, running on a Linux arm64 instance.  As you can see there is a very tiny difference if you do entirely rational arithmetic.

I get the same results with LW and with CCL running under Rosetta.

For double argument to the function I *also* get no difference if I just use doubles rather than rationals for the numerator (see `set-params` function below for how to set that up).

Thus I conclude that, with high probability, you are not running the code you think you are.  Possible alternatives is buggy floating point somewhere or perhaps a buggy version of SBCL: both are probably unlikely here.

My code is below.

```
(in-package :cl-user)

;;; these are the values in the question
;;;

(defvar *given-numerator-scaled*
  '(5690652191347156388090791033559122686859/100000000000000000000000000000000
    518970215581722725953135526808035119277/5000000000000000000000000000000
    4318156564406929572773463644488934211171/50000000000000000000000000000000
    866777786493522766954744748118106663217/20000000000000000000000000000000
    1460557808768506808414169982791359218571/100000000000000000000000000000000
    87042803874516147720517754741193639117/25000000000000000000000000000000
    6018596171681098786670226533699352302507/10000000000000000000000000000000000
    1899982326003635662468825860899727284273/25000000000000000000000000000000000
    3477999801257688070178155057757599493763/500000000000000000000000000000000000
    4499445569063168119446858607650988409623/10000000000000000000000000000000000000
    121999549265476092677991310389728258513/6250000000000000000000000000000000000
    5098416655656676188125178644804694509993/10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    3030921173124453262891876982277968441611/500000000000000000000000000000000000000000))

(defvar *given-denominator* '(0
                  39916800
                  120543840
                  150917976
                  105258076
                  45995730
                  13339535
                  2637558
                  357423
                  32670
                  1925
                  66
                  1))

(defvar *lanczos-13-numerator-scaled*)
(defvar *lanczos-13-denominator*)

(defun set-params (&key float-numerator)
  (setf *lanczos-13-numerator-scaled*
        (coerce (if float-numerator
                    (mapcar (lambda (r)
                              (float r 1.0d0))
                            *given-numerator-scaled*)
                    *given-numerator-scaled*)
                'vector)
        *lanczos-13-denominator* (coerce *given-denominator* 'vector))
  float-numerator)

(set-params)
  
(defun evaluate-rational (numerator denominator z)
  (assert (= (length numerator)
             (length denominator)) () "Numerator and denominator must be of the same length")
  (let (s1 s2)
    (if (<= z 1)
        (progn
          (setf s1 (aref numerator   (1- (length numerator)))
                s2 (aref denominator (1- (length denominator))))
          (loop for i from (- (length numerator) 2) downto 0
                do  (setf s1 (* s1 z)
                          s1 (+ s1 (aref numerator i))
                          s2 (* s2 z)
                          s2 (+ s2 (aref denominator i)))))
      (progn
        (setf z (/ z)
              s1 (aref numerator 0)
              s2 (aref denominator 0))
        (loop for i from 1 below (length numerator)
              do (setf s1 (* s1 z)
                       s1 (+ s1 (aref numerator i))
                       s2 (* s2 z)
                       s2 (+ s2 (aref denominator i)))
                 )))
    (/ s1 s2)))

(defun lanczos-sum (x &key (scaled t))
  "Return the Lanczos sum for x, exp(g), possibly normalised"
  (if scaled
      (evaluate-rational *lanczos-13-numerator-scaled* *lanczos-13-denominator* x)
    (error "not implemented")))

(defparameter *sample-double*
  ;; Sample double in the question
  79.50051116943359375d0)
(defparameter *cephes-answer*
  ;; Answer from C++ in the question
  0.007539542760993982d0)

(defun ts ()
  (let ((*lanczos-13-numerator-scaled* *lanczos-13-numerator-scaled*)
        (*lanczos-13-denominator* *lanczos-13-denominator*))
    (set-params)
    (let ((dd (- *cephes-answer* (lanczos-sum *sample-double*)))
          (rd (- *cephes-answer* (lanczos-sum (rationalize
                                               *sample-double*)))))
      (set-params :float-numerator t)
      (values dd rd
              (- *cephes-answer* (lanczos-sum *sample-double*))
              (- *cephes-answer* (lanczos-sum (rationalize
                                               *sample-double*)))))))
```

Comment: Do you want to share those coefficients?  I've just added the code that I used to generate rational coefficients using CLISP, and they agree with the original post, as well as the code you posted in a spot check of a few.

Comment: @CL-USER: I have amended my answer and include all the coefficients now: I think my coefficients are the same as yours, but the problem is not reproducable.  Almost certain you are not running the code you think you are.

Comment: Well now, that *is* interesting.  I have confirmed the correct code is being run and updated the original post. Yet, on both CLISP and SBCL the results agree with each other, and differ from your tests with CMUCL, LW and CCL.  I also tried CLISP on Linux just to eliminate any potential platform problems, with the same result.

Comment: @CL-USER: sorry, I *am* using SBCL: not sure why I wrote CMUCL which I don't even have.  Run *my* code.  There is a `ts` function which returns four values, the first two are double & rationalized-double with rational coefficients, the second are double & rationalized double with double coefficients.  All but the second should be `0.0d0`.

Comment: Your code works.  What I can't see is *why* -- you're running the same code for lanczos-sum and evaluate-rational as I am (at least this is what it looks like at the end of a long day).  I'm thrilled it looks like there's an easy solution, yet mystified why there's a difference in our results.  Will have to dig into this tomorrow.

Comment: The answer to 'why', is a single digit error (and in the least significant position) of a coefficient in the denominator.  I focused so much attention on the numerator, I didn't consider looking at the denominator, which seemed simple.  So, you were correct, I wasn't running the code I thought I was.

Comment: @CL-USER: Oh, I'm glad you found it!  I have spend many hours failing to find things like that!